# Intercepting 7 segment display control on a proprietary PCB with unknown IC

Tags: 7segmentdisplay, reverse-engineering

So I'm trying to intercept the control of the 7-segment display on body weight scale to display huuuge negative numbers on remote control (to prank my friend).

I've cracked the scale open and inspected the PCB.
Turns out it uses a pre-configured closed source IC connected to 4 weight sensors and 4 metal pads (which documentation describes as body fat sensors - although i assume they are irrelevant to the task).

The connection from IC to the display is managed through 7 common anode LED driver. Because the display is significantly more complex then just 7 LED's i assumed there is either a matrix (similar to the keyboard one) or a hex decoder embedded into the display.

Sadly the pins are connected to solder pads underneath which seem to only emerge again on the other side which is glued to the display, and the Styrofoam casing of the display makes it very risky to remove it.

The IC does have a connection to 4 pins labeled `VDD, GND, SCK, SDA` which I assumed is the I2C debug interface. Then I run an Arduino script to determine the address of the IC but it didn't find any. But I'm positive that the pins are connected since its possible to power the IC through them.

So far I've considered 3 ways I could get control of the 7-segment display:

- Writing to the registers of the IC using I2C protocol to determine the relation between the registers and the display. Then wiring some MCU with Bluetooth capabilities.
- Directly supplying data to the pads under the LED driver pins (I'm not able to remove the IC as they used some very strange solder, my iron is not able to melt it. This makes me hesitant as I risk frying the IC through LED driver pins.)
- Supplying different voltage on the wires from the pressure sensor (This wont allow me to get negative values sadly)

I've tried #3 and realized it does not work for my use case.

Could anyone suggest, how should I approach the task? Also is it legal to write and read memory of the closed source IC?

**Update:**
To ensure i2c on Arduino works I tested it with an OLED. It does work, I've also noticed that connecting via i2c seems to cause significantly longer light up of 7-segment on start.

**Update:**
Just noticed skimming through the product description manufacturer provides that I2C is in fact never mentioned, instead they call it two wire communication protocol clock and data respectively. Not sure if its just the way they name I2C or if its some I2C flavor specialized for their device.

**Update:**
So I've found something resembling an uncomplete datasheet on manufacturers webpage. I've adjusted the frequency but no luck detecting the address.

I've decided to try request bytes using Arduino on oxo address and surprisingly got some data. The fact that it returns identical data every run while the ic is powered makes me think its not some garbage data.

I've managed to remove the screen cover on the other side of PCB. It has a lot of LED's and numerous pads labeled LED1, LED2, ... .
I tend to believe that each pad corresponds to certain pin on the IC, however supplying voltage to either pin (with debug ground being connected to ground) lights up a group of seemingly unrelated (but always the same) LED's. Supplying voltage to individual LED causes either multiple LED's to shine very dim and one (not particularly the contacted one) very bright, or has no effect.

[image: Back of the pcb]

**Update:**
I tried powering up multiple LED pads at the time thinking that it will reduce number of LEDS lighting up allowing for selection, but no luck.

Comment: It is quite common for manufacturers to avoid the term 'i2c' when describing a protocol that may be identical to i2c, due to patent/trademark issues. The SCK and SDA labels do suggest i2c, but 'two wire protocol' can also cover some proprietary non-i2c transfer methods.

Comment: Do you have an oscilloscope? Or even one of those little USB logic analyzers

Comment: @user253751 i do, but not in the immediate access. Gotta go to hackerspace.

Comment: @HerbalTea do it! :) connect the thing back together, scope the I2C wires and you will be able to see how the microcontroller communicates with the display controller, e.g. what address, and you should be able to match it with the datasheet